# DataFrame won't assign values to new pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add all values from pandas DataFrames `df1.Number` to `df2.Number` where the date ranges match.
I have a created `df1` which looks as such:

```
       Start        End  Number
0 2000-01-01 2000-01-08       1
1 2000-01-02 2000-01-09       2
2 2000-01-03 2000-01-10       3
3 2000-01-04 2000-01-11       4
4 2000-01-05 2000-01-12       5
5 2000-01-06 2000-01-13       6
6 2000-01-07 2000-01-14       7
```

and df2 which looks as such:

```
        Dates Number
0  2000-01-01       
1  2000-01-02       
2  2000-01-03       
3  2000-01-04       
4  2000-01-05       
5  2000-01-06       
6  2000-01-07       
7  2000-01-08       
8  2000-01-09       
9  2000-01-10       
10 2000-01-11       
11 2000-01-12       
12 2000-01-13       
13 2000-01-14
```

and I am trying to assign `Number` from `df1` to `Number` in `df2` if the date range in the rows match

The code I have used is for the first row is:

```
i = pd.date_range(df1.Start[0], df1.End[0])

if df2.Dates in i:
    df2.Number.assign(df1.Number)
```

which does not throw an error but also does not assign anything to `Number`. Expected output should be as follows:

```
        Dates Number
0  2000-01-01 1     
1  2000-01-02 1,2      
2  2000-01-03 1,2,3    
3  2000-01-04 1,2,3,4 
4  2000-01-05 1,2,3,4,5
5  2000-01-06 1,2,3,4,5,6      
6  2000-01-07 1,2,3,4,5,6,7    
7  2000-01-08 1,2,3,4,5,6,7   
8  2000-01-09 2,3,4,5,6,7
9  2000-01-10 3,4,5,6,7
10 2000-01-11 4,5,6,7
11 2000-01-12 5,6,7
12 2000-01-13 6,7 
13 2000-01-14 7
```

Can anyone suggest why nothing is being assigned or a code that would do this for all rows? Thanks.

Comment: do you ever enter the if condition? my guess it you don't

Comment: @Yuca new to programming so unsure of what that means? Can't see to find any docs on it.

Comment: do this `if df2.Dates in i:
    print('entered')
    df2.Number.assign(df1.Number)`

Comment: @coldspeed yes, which is why expected output contain all numbers where that row's ranges overlap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `numpy` broadcast with `dot`

```
s1=df1.Start.values
s2=df1.End.values
s=df2.Dates.values[:,None]
pd.Series(((s1<=s)&(s2>=s)).dot(df1.Number.astype(str)+','),index=df2.index).str[:-1]
#df2['Number']=pd.Series(((s1<=s)&(s2>=s)).dot(df1.Number.astype(str)+','),index=df2.index).str[:-1]
Out[229]: 
0                 1
1               1,2
2             1,2,3
3           1,2,3,4
4         1,2,3,4,5
5       1,2,3,4,5,6
6     1,2,3,4,5,6,7
7     1,2,3,4,5,6,7
8       2,3,4,5,6,7
9         3,4,5,6,7
10          4,5,6,7
11            5,6,7
12              6,7
13                7
dtype: object
```

Comment: This hasn't got the `Dates` column in there which is a DateTimeIndex and what I need to base a time series off.

Comment: @geds133 try my mask line #

Comment: @geds133 yw : -) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it:

```
s = df2.apply(lambda x: [((df1.loc[i,'Start'] < x) & (df1.loc[i,'End'] > x))
                        for i in range(len(df1))], axis = 1)

df2.assign(**s.apply(lambda x: np.unique(np.cumsum(x)) + 1).to_frame(name='Number'))

    Dates                 Number
0  2000-01-01                    [1]
1  2000-01-02                    [2]
2  2000-01-03                 [2, 3]
3  2000-01-04              [2, 3, 4]
4  2000-01-05           [2, 3, 4, 5]
5  2000-01-06        [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
6  2000-01-07     [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
7  2000-01-08  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
8  2000-01-09     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
9  2000-01-10        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
10 2000-01-11           [1, 2, 3, 4]
11 2000-01-12              [1, 2, 3]
12 2000-01-13                 [1, 2]
13 2000-01-14                    [1]
```

**Note**

Make sure the dates are in datetime format:

```
df1.Start = pd.to_datetime(df1.Start)
df1.End = pd.to_datetime(df1.End)
df2.Dates = pd.to_datetime(df2.Dates)
```

Comment: This does not produce the same output for me. Any suggestions why mine does not contain any information in `Number`.

Comment: The only difference is that I've deleted the empty `Number` column in df2, and added it a posteriori

Comment: They are in datetime format but still doesn't produce any output. Strange